# Show the Helix is Homeomorphic to the line

Tags: general-topology

How do I show the helix given by s↦(cos2πs, sin2πs, s) for s∈ℝ is homeomorphic to the vertical line, its axis. I'm confused because the function is parametric and the inverse trigonometric relations are 0ne-to-many.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe by exhibiting such homeomorphism. If you take $(\alpha \cos(2\pi s),\alpha \sin(2\pi s), s)$ and take the limit when $\alpha\to 0$ you get a line. But I'm not sure if it's an homeomorphism because the reciprocal function is not defined for $\alpha=0$.

Comment: The inverse is projection onto the third coordinate, $(x,y,z) \to z$. (Nothing to do with inverse trig.) Just check that this projection, and also the defining parametrization are continuous, and check that they are inverses. If you considered $s \to (cos (s), sin(s))$, then the map would not be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Just show that the function you describe mapping the real line to the helix is an homeomorphism!

Remember, you have to check that the mapping is

1) Bijective - that is, one to one and total.
2) Bicontinuous - that is, continuous with a continuous inverse image.

Comment: Could you confirm the mapping I proposed is not a homeomorphism because of the singularity in the inverse image?

Comment: The map you posted is a homeomorphism for $\alpha = 0$, and indeed for all real $\alpha$; it's just the topological embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ onto the $z$-axis.